# Play Framework : how to not watch a folder for changes in Play Framework

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.2

I am using Play 2.2.3. 
I am new to Play and SBT. I want to make Play not watch a folder during development. In this case, a node_modules folder under public folder.
I tried these below but it did not seems to work. Also, I dont' know what is the difference between watchSources and playMonitoredFiles.

```
    .settings(
  playMonitoredFiles <<= playMonitoredFiles map { (files: Seq[String]) =>
    files.filterNot(file => file.contains("node_modules"))
  }
)
.settings(
  watchSources <<= watchSources map { (sources: Seq[java.io.File]) =>
    sources
      .filterNot(source => source.isFile && source.getPath.contains("node_modules") )
      .filterNot(source => source.isDirectory && source.getPath.contains("node_modules"))
  }
)
.settings(
  watchSources := watchSources.value.filter { !_.getPath.contains("node_modules")  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Note***: The original question was about a legacy release (2.2.3), however I found useful the same question for modern versions.

So basically **watchSources** is a SBT key used for the [triggered-execution](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Triggered-Execution.html#Triggered+Execution) functionality.

On the contrary, **playMonitoredFiles** is a TaskKey defined by the PlayFramework sbt-plugin, which controls a set of directories to watch by
the development server (sbt run) for the auto-reloading functionality.

When launching an sbt run, for EVERY REQUEST, there is a check of the directories defined by *playMonitoredFiles* and if any change is found,
a silent re-compilation is triggered. This means shutting down the server, recompiling and starting again.

The default values for playMonitoredFiles are calculated in [playMonitoredFilesTask](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/47f277b5357455cb8759e4b4fe0ebe3bc605368b/dev-mode/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayCommands.scala#L90).

So for example, we have a certain version file added to our resources, computed in each compilation. We needed PlayFramework to avoid checking changes on this file
on development, because on every-request, the auto-recompiling regenerated this file and play marked the sources to be recompiled again, however no java files were recompiled and
nothing is printed out, so we had to debug the application in order to find the issue.
This setting only applies to development server (sbt run).

Within a project settings in **build.sbt**, the task can be overridden to exclude a directory (in the example, target/version directory):

```
.settings(
...,
playMonitoredFiles := playMonitoredFiles.value.filterNot {
    _.getPath() endsWith String.format("target%sversion", File.separator)
  }
...,
)
```

The value is of type *File* and only contains directories.